# Page navigation with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) and I'm having some trouble implementing the page navigation.

The navigation links looks like this:

```
<a href="#Profile">Profile</a>
```

This would change the browser URL to append `#Profile`. Running fiddler it seems it doesn't cause the page to refresh (no traffic is passed).

This doesn't seem to be documented in the Bootstrap documentation and since I don't even know the name of the feature I haven't managed to look up how to implement it properly. Can anyone tell me what its called and possibly provide an explanation or some documentation?

Comment: That sounds perfect. If you post your comment as an answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested:

A link prefaced with # triggers a [`hashChange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange) event, and scrolls the current page to an element with an `id`equal to Profile (so: `<div id="Profile>...</div>`). This isn't a [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) feature, it's purely HTML.

Note that this is true of a link as posted in your question: `<a href="#Profile">Profile</a>`

Should the link's `href` have the form: `<a href="http://example.com/index.html#Profile">Profile</a>`

then it will load a new page, and immediately scroll to the element of `id="Profile"`. This is useful for linking to specific portions of other pages (my own predominant use-case for this is to link to specific portions of Quirksmode's compatibility, or the W3's, HTML/CSS docs).